# List index with for-loops python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, for-loop, attributes

This is my code:

```
class People:

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"A('{self.name}', {self.age}, {self.height})"

    def __init__(self, name, age, height):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.height = height

def sorted_list():
    people = []
    fil = open('peoples.txt', 'r').readlines()

    for i in file:
        i = i.split()
        people.append(People(i[0], (i[1]))
    people.sort(key=lambda a: (a.age, a.name))
```

My text file looks like this:

```
List:
Anna 13
Mark 44
James 80
Hanna 45
```

I want the attribute "height" to represent each persons position in the list using a for-loop. My code already sorts the people in the list according to their age, from youngest to oldest. Now I want the code to use a for-loop so that the attribute height gives each person from the sorted list their position in the list, i.e. gives Anna number 1, Hanna number 2 , Mark number 3 and James number 4.

This is what I've tried so far but it doesn't work:

```
i = 0
    for height in people:
        i += 1
        people.height = int(i)
        people = sorted(people)

    return people
```

Does anyone have an idea for what I could do?

Comment: You don't need to call sorted inside loop. Also you can use enumerate() function to get index in loop.(https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do so you can iterate using loop with [range](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range):

```
for i in range(len(people)):
    # + 1 to start enumeration with 1 instead of 0
    people[i].height = i + 1
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, you can use enumerate like below

```
i = 0 # starting point
for height, people_obj in enumerate(people, i):
    people_obj.height = height
# sort your list people
```